# JavaScript IndexOf with heterogeneous array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

javascript indexOf function is not working with mix type of array. any other alternatives

```
 var myArray = ["2","3",5]
    var found = [];
    var range = 10;

    for (var i = 1; i < range; i++){
        if(myArray.indexOf(i) === -1)
        {
              found .push(i);
        }
    }


    console.log(found)
```

output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Expected output : [1,4,6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: where is `usedVlans` assigned?

Comment: What is the intent behind this code?  you are looking up the indexes of the array as members of it.

Comment: was updating the question

Comment: With the update `5` is missing because it's found within the array. Again, what is the intent here - I can only speak of what the code does in terms of instructions, I'm not clear if the instructions given are even correct for the task.

Comment: So you want an array range `[1,range)`, excluding numbers and numeric strings from `myArray`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Because `myArray.indexOf(5)` is `2` and not `-1`

Comment: `"2" === 2` is `false`, hence why `indexOf` doesn't find it.

Comment: @VLAZ what are the alternatives?

Comment: I'd say make the array all one type first. It makes more sense. Or if it *needs* to have mixed types, then check using `some`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why 5 is missing  ?

```js
console.log(5 === "5")
```

`indexOf(5)` isn't `-1` because `5` and `"5"` are two different value ( indexOf uses strict equality ) [`MDN indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description)

```js
console.log([5].indexOf(5))
console.log(["5"].indexOf(5))
```

> How can i match both `5` or `"5"` ?

Check for both numeric and string value.

```js
var myArray = ["2", "3", 5]
var found = [];
var range = 10;

for (var i = 1; i < range; i++) {
  if (myArray.indexOf(i) === -1 && myArray.indexOf(String(i)) === -1) {
    found.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var myArray = ["2","3",5]
 var found = [];
 var range = 10;

var tmpArr = myArray.map(function(elm) { 
  return elm.toString(); 
 });
 
 for (var i = 1; i < range; i++){
    if(tmpArr.indexOf(i.toString()) === -1) {
        found .push(i);
    }
}

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for both strings and numbers as 
[5] and ["5"] are treated differently because their types are different. i.e String and Number

```js
var myArray = ["2", "3", 5]
var found = [];
var range = 10;
for (var i = 1; i < range; i++) {
  if (myArray.indexOf(String(i)) === -1 && myArray.indexOf(i) === -1) {
    found.push(i);
  }
}
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of use case, like to check if a value exists in a collection, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with numbers as values and check this values agains a set of wanted numbers.

[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) takes a strict comparison and returns the index only if the value has the same identity ([Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)).

```js
var array = ["2", "3", 5],
    values = new Set(array.map(Number)),
    found = [],
    range = 10,
    v;

for (v = 1; v < range; v++) if (!values.has(v)) found.push(v);

console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `myArray.indexOf(5)` is `2` and not `-1`.

```js
var myArray = ["2","3",5]
var found = [];
var range = 10;

for (var i = 1; i < range; i++){
  console.log(i);
  if(myArray.indexOf(i) === -1){
    found .push(i);
  }
}

console.log(found)
```

More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 0):

okay as you need you expected result as  [1,4,6, 7, 8, 9]

then you have to make some changes in if condition.
why i will let you know first-run code snippet

```js
 var myArray = ["2","3",5]
    var found = [];
    var range = 10;

  for (var i = 1; i < range; i++){
        if(myArray.indexOf(i) === -1 && myArray.indexOf(String(i)) === -1)
        {
              found.push(i);
        }
    }


    console.log(found)
```

`myArray.indexOf(i) === -1` as you added 
why `myArray.indexOf(String(i)) === -1` because you have heterogeneous data.
int and string type data.

Comment: `''+i+''` is useless - `''+i'` will do the implicit conversion to string, adding another empty string does nothing.

Comment: yes we can do! i just write like this to give a understanding that I am converting the `i` int value to string. :)

Comment: Again, `''+i` does the string conversion, the second empty string is completely useless, it doesn't change anything and it doesn't even make it any clearer - the idiomatic implicit conversion is empty string first, then concatenation, then the numeric value: `"" + i`. If you want to be clearer than that, then use explicit conversion: `String(i)`. Using a non-idiomatic construct doesn't make it any more understandable what is happening, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

[Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) only does strict equality to find the value, so because `"2" === 2` and `"3" === 3` are both `false`, then `myArray.indexOf(i)` returns `-1` for `i` having the value `2` or `3`.

If you want to look through an array of mixed types for only one type, then it's probably easier to make the array only one type first:

```js
var myArray = ["2", "3", 5]
var found = [];
var range = 10;

//convery all to numbers
myArray = myArray.map(Number);

for (var i = 1; i < range; i++) {
  if (myArray.indexOf(i) === -1) {
    found.push(i);
  }
}


console.log(found);
```

Alternatively, if the array has to stay with mixed types, you can use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check for presence and supply logic that is independent of types:

```js
var myArray = ["2", "3", 5]
var found = [];
var range = 10;

for (var i = 1; i < range; i++) {
  //lookup using loose equals
  var inArray = myArray
    .some(item => item == i);
  if (!inArray) {
    found.push(i);
  }
}


console.log(found);
```